# How to get the Email id of signed in user - Meteor?

Tags: email, meteor, accounts

I have deployed an app under meteor.com which can be logged in using social media connections.  Meteor accounts-facebook accounts-twitter accounts-google packages used.

But this Meteor app doesn't return email id of the signed in user ever after publishing "emails".

We used to get email id of the logged in user with the following code, but now its not working.

```
Meteor.user().emails[0].address
```

Codes in my app:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: { emails: 1, profile: 1 } });
});
```

Client:

```
Template.layout.events({
    'click #checkUser':function(){
        var user = Meteor.user();
        var email = user && user.emails && user.emails[0].address

        alert(email);
    }
})
```

but this function returns "undefined"

Please help

Comment: what is in your `settings.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package `meteor add splendido:accounts-emails-field` https://atmospherejs.com/splendido/accounts-emails-field

> This is a Meteor package which maintains the registered_emails array
>   field inside the user object up to date with any account service email
>   used by the user to login into the application.

so when you use this package doesn't matter how the user signed up you will always have it also at `Meteor.user().registered_emails` and `Meteor.user().registered_emails[0].address` should work now.

UPDATE: you will have to publish this information to the client you can do this below and subscribe to it where you need it or change `user` to `null` and it will publish it automatically for everyone.

```
Meteor.publish("user", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {'registered_emails': 1}});
  } else {
    return [];
  };
});
```

Comment: added the package you mentioned and changed my code

`'click #mobileuser':function(){
  var userEmail = Meteor.user().registered_emails[0].address;
  alert(userEmail);
 }`


but still the result is the same.
`

Comment: @MaheshBabu can you logout + re login after you added this package? It work based on login callback also I guess you have to publish this extra information on the client forgot about that I will update the answer